# Mobile Phone Chargers

Tags: batteries

What if I'll charge my phone and then suddenly unplug it. And then charge again, then unplug again. Does it will cause a harm to the phone?

Comment: Why would you do that in the first place ?

Answer (score 3):

Probably not.  Presumably the charger in the phone is sophisticated enough to manage the battery properly regardless of when you do or don't supply charging power.

Comment: I'm disappointed that someone who at least gives the appearance of caring about site quality posted this. Apart from 3 x 10k delete votes on the question this will stick around forever and encourage more of the same.

Comment: @Peter: Yeah, I was on the fence about closing or giving a quick answer.  I kept the answer short since I thought the question might be closed, and frankly this question didn't deserve more than that anyway.